# Fedora 20 - Use defined webapps fonts

Tags: fedora, browser

I am a web developer. Everyone who works in this business knows how important the look and feel is (I mean take a look at apple). When I'm browsing my application via Chrome or Firefox i see a difference than browsing from a windows system. The fonts are just not the same. So instead of `Tahoma` I see another font from my Fedora system. It is really important, that the font should be not indiviual, more like what the webapp defines. Do you know what I mean?

Take a look at the printscreens:
[image: snapshot1.png]
is from a Fedora system and
[image: snapshot6.png]
is from a Windows system(both with Chrome)

Comment: If the font is of such importantance you should incorporate it in your CSS and not assume that a client system has it installed. Or at least specify a reasonable general alternative ([`sans-serif`](http://css-tricks.com/sans-serif/)). Such things have nothing to do with Linux, Windows or any other OS.

Comment: If you are concerned about looks, you should IMHO start with consistency in casing of 'i' or 'I' in mid sentence.

Comment: Or, if you insist on having MS fonts, try http://pkgs.org/fedora-centos-rhel-opensuse-mandriva/olea/webcore-fonts-3.0-1.noarch.rpm.html

Answer (score 0):

You're using proprietary platform-specific font names (Tahoma, in this case) so no wonder it behaves differently on different platforms. While Microsoft did eventually start distributing Tahoma and such for use on other platforms to try and solve this, it's still not going to solve the problem on systems where the MS font pack hasn't yet been installed. Consider Android, for example, which only uses the [Ascender](http://www.droidfonts.com) family.

The proper solution is to use some kind of web font technology which allows the browser to download the font from a central location, so it doesn't matter what fonts are installed locally. One free option for this is [the Google Fonts library](http://www.google.com/fonts/).

This does add to the download "weight" of your page, but that's the cost of cross-platform consistency.

Even then, don't expect pixel-perfect consistency. The web was purposefully designed to give the browser considerable freedom in how it renders your web page.